# Import Facebook comments into Disqus

Tags: javascript, facebook, migration, disqus

I'm migrating my website comment system from Facebook to Disqus. The problem is that it seems I will lost all the comments I already had...
Disqus uses the Facebook API for a few things, but can it retrieve the comments as well? Is there a way I can "migrate them"?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that manually using the Graph API to export your Facebook comments, then import them to Disqus.

Comment: But there is no script to do the conversion?